# Try to create rain fall in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I learn javascript and  i try to create a rain falling in js but have a problem. After many tries i code something like this. First version of my app can simulate to rain for only one rain drop and now i'd like to translate it to many of rain drops

```js
function Raining() {
  setInterval(Raining, 40)
  if (yPosition < 1000) {
    yPosition += step
  } else {
    yPosition = 0
    rain.style.top = 0
  }
}

//Rain
let xPosition;
let yPosition = 0;
const step = .5


//Making water
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  const el = document.createElement('div')
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el)
  //Random x location
  let randomXPosition = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
  el.style.left = `${randomXPosition}%`
}
let rain = document.querySelectorAll('div')
for (i = 0; i < rain.length; i++) {
  rain[i].style.top = `${yPosition}px`
  Raining()
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 3px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rain"></div>
```

Code execute only once . I know that here is a lot of mistakes but please help what's wrong here.

Comment: You need to keep/read/change the yPosition of *each* drop. You currently only have a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one rain

This works better but you really ned a random step for each drop

```js
function Raining() {
  yPosition += step;

  for (i = 0; i < rain.length; i++) {
    yPosition += Math.floor(Math.random()*i)
    rain[i].style.top = `${yPosition}px`
  }
  if (yPosition > 1000) {
    yPosition = 0
  }
}

//Rain
let xPosition;
let yPosition = 0;
const step = .5

//Making water
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const el = document.createElement('div')
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el)
  //Random x location
  let randomXPosition = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
  el.style.left = `${randomXPosition}%`
}
let rain = document.querySelectorAll('div')

setInterval(Raining, 300)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 3px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rain"></div>
```